# Changing an item in a list C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have an object called Cars, then a List of objects called Colours. These Colours are the posible colours the car can come with. For Example:

```
Car audi = new Car();
audi.Colours.Add("Black");
audi.Colours.Add("Silver");
audi.Colours.Add("White");
```

Now lets theoretically these could be in any order, so I can't simply use an index.

I know I can get an item using:

```
audi.Colours.Find(colour => colour.Name == "Silver");
```

How would I change the Silver item to "Swanky Diamond" without rebuilding the whole list?

In the real life situation I'm building the list from a database and I have a unique identifier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using a foreach loop to find the item and then modifying to after the loop?

Comment: Because that would be considered an unethical way of approaching such a task for reasons such as:

* messy code.
* long list could cause performance issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a list indexer setter, like this:

```
var index = audi.Colours.IndexOf("Silver");
if (index >= 0) {
    audi.Colours[index] = "Swanky Diamond";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the items aren't conceptually ordered then use a `HashSet`, rather than a `List`.

To see if an item is contained in the set, use `Contains`.

```
if(audi.Colours.Contains("Silver")) 
{
}
```

To replace one item with another remove the item you wish to remove, and add the item you wish to add:

```
audi.Colours.Remove("Silver");
audi.Colours.Add("Swanky Diamond");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int zeroBasedIndex = audi.Colors.IndexOf("Silver")
if (zeroBasedIndex != -1)
    audi.Colors[zeroBasedIndex] = "Swanky Diamond";
else
    //Item Not In List
```

Comment: I don't think `Insert` will replace the item at the given index, which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is adding a new color to the list.  The Question is about modifying an existing item in the list

Comment: you posted your comment after I had already removed that, was a Haven't Had my Coffee Yet mistake =p

Comment: You people are still posting comments and one upping comments that don't make sense anymore, read the UPDATED comments and answer if you want a good answer.   @Scott, No, It Won't, I forgot to remove it but in place replacement using array indexing is better so i removed that, @ saggio I fixed it before you posted this, irrelevant.

Comment: Can't beat the sheep following the high reppers to just upvote everything they post, I beat him to it and still get the short end of the stick. I hope the OP finds my answer useful